# Can you tag inbound Name on inbound rules on an AWS security group using terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to set individual names against each entry in my security group.

My example code that doesn't work below, I'd expect this to yield the result in the picture but the Name tag remains blank (i set this one as an example in the picture through the console). This tag works other places like the "Allow-Google" name tag against the security group. Is there a way I can achieve this ?

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow-google-dns" {
  name        = "allow-google-dns"
  description = "Allows google dns"
  vpc_id      = var.vpcid

  ingress = [
    {
      description      = "allows google in"
      from_port        = 0
      to_port          = 0
      protocol         = "-1"
      cidr_blocks = ["8.8.8.8/32" ]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
      prefix_list_ids = []
      security_groups = []
      self = false
      tags = {
    Name = "MyName"
           }
    }
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "Allow-Google"
  }
}
```

[AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPrQw.png)

Comment: Its too new, and not supported yet by TF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248823/marcin) is right (for the time being).

As of Terraform 1.0.7 with version 3.60.0 of the AWS provider, tagging rules isn't supported, neither in inline format or in external `aws_security_group_rule` resources.

But Terraform doesn't notice any tags that are in place, so you could conceivably add them after creation, and Terraform won't detect it as a change whenever you reapply.

Comment: It's been a year now, does anyone know if this is still the case?

Comment: Answering my own comment, it appears that it's on the [roadmap](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/ROADMAP.md), see: [Resource Identifiers and Tags for VPC Security Group Rules #20104](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20104).

Comment: @dossy thanks for the find! That feature has now shipped in Terraform AWS Provider v4.40.0+ : [Resource Identifiers and Tags for VPC Security Group Rules
#20104](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20104#issuecomment-1315912353)